# Array Java con archivo txt

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código :

```
 Iterator<cuenta> cuentasR =caja.iterator();
          int contador = 0;

     cuenta p = cuentasR.next();
     while(cuentasR.hasNext()){
            break;
}
```

En el cual recorro un archivo de txt con el siguiente formato :
1000001,400
1000002,200
1000003,500
1000004,800

Estoy haciendo un cajero en el cual 1000001 es el número de cuenta y 400 el saldo. como puedo recorrer el archivo y mediante un JOptionPane ingresar el número de cuenta y que me diga el saldo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar FileReader y BuffederReader para hacer tu cajero. Necesitarás hacer uso de algo como split que te separa String con un separador. Es sencillito de usar.

```
FileReader f=new FileReader("DireccionDeTuFichero");
BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(f);
//y recorrerle hasta encontrar lo que buscas
String cad; //cadena auxiliar
while((cad=b.readLine())!=null){
  String parts[]=cad.split(","); //Aquí poner el separador del txt, que en tu caso es ,
```

.
.
.
A partir de ahí ya tendrías en parts[0] el numero de cuenta y en parts[1] el saldo. Como está dentro de un while, recorrerás todo el archivo. Teniendo otra cuenta en una variable, sólo sería compararlo con parts[0] y cuando coincida devolver parts[1]

Recuerda hacer b.close() y f.close() cuando el while termine

Comment: Primero debe hacer split por espacio y luego cada elemento por coma. Para ahorrarse close puede usar try-with-resources

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, serían 2 splits, 1 para espacios primero y una vez ya los tengas separados y metidos en otro almacén de datos, (una lista mismamente) habrá que hacer otro split  con las comas

Comment: Entonces seria uso del split usando el FileReader y BuffederReader, lo que no logro hacer es la condicion dentro del while. Ya la hice con if pero el while se queda recorriendo todos los elementos.

Comment: FileReader f=new FileReader("DireccionDeTuFichero");
BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(f);
//y recorrerle hasta encontrar lo que buscas
String cad; //cadena auxiliar
while((cad=b.readLine())!=null){
  String parts[]=cad.split(",");   if()//condicion para verificar la cuenta

Comment: El primer split que hacer será String [] var= cad.split(" "); Ahí separarás las cuentas entre sí. Ya tienes un array de cuentas con su saldo en tu array var[]. Ahora, desde ese array mismamente, o si lo pasas a un ArrayList por ejemplo, cogeremos cada uno de los elementos y le haremos otro split(",") esta vez para separar cuentas de saldos. Obviamente esto hay que hacerlo en un bucle for para recorrer toda la lista de cuentas.

Comment: No me salio amigo, igual no puedo guardar una posision en una variable por que es string la cadena y no puedo convertirla a int.

Comment: Se pueden convertir de int a String fácilmente con Integer.toString(numero). Si lo quieres hacer con numeros enteros declara los arrays como enteros. También servirá seguramente.